# failed dependencies when install diamondback

Tags: ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have tried sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-pr2-desktop successfully

```
 sam@/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/laser_drivers/hokuyo_node$ sudo apt-get      install ros-diamondback-pr2-desktop
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 ros-diamondback-pr2-desktop is already the newest version.
 The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer      required:
   libantlr-dev python-sip4-dev
 Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
 
 sam@/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/laser_drivers/hokuyo_node$
```

When I run

```
 sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-*
```

it shows

```
  ros-diamondback-graspit-simulator : Depends: libqt4-sql-psql but it is not      going to be installed
  ros-diamondback-warehousewg : Depends: xulrunner-dev but it is not going      to be installed
 E: Broken packages
```

My /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
 sam@/home/sam/code/ros/gazebo/debug$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
 # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 10.10 _Maverick Meerkat_ - Release amd64      (20101007)]/ maverick main restricted
 # See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade      to
 # newer versions of the distribution.
 
 deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main restricted
 deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main restricted
 
 ## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
 ## distribution.
 
 ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the      Ubuntu
 ## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
 ## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
 deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick universe
 deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick universe
 
 ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the      Ubuntu 
 ## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
 ## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
 ## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
 ## security team.
 deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick multiverse
 deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick multiverse
 
 ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
 ## repository.
 ## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
 ## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
 ## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
 ## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
 ## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
 # deb http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-backports main      restricted universe multiverse
 # deb-src http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-backports main      restricted universe multiverse
 
 ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
 ## 'partner' repository.
 ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
 ## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
 # deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner
 # deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner
 
 ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
 ## developers who want to ship their latest software.
 deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main
 deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main
```

I run 'dpkg -s xulrunner-dev      libqt4-sql-psql':

```
 sam@/home/sam/code/ros/gazebo/debug$ dpkg -s xulrunner-dev      libqt4-sql-psql
 Package `xulrunner-dev' is not installed and no info is available.
 
 Package `libqt4-sql-psql' is not installed and no info is available.
 Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
 and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
 
 sam@/home/sam/code/ros/gazebo/debug$
```

I run 'sudo apt-get install libqt4-sql-psql':

```
 sam@/home/sam/code/ros/sam_nav/ira_navigation/teleop_ira_robot/launch$      export LANG=en_US
 
 sam@/home/sam/code/ros/sam_nav/ira_navigation/teleop_ira_robot/launch$      export LC_MESSAGE=en_US.UTF8
 
 sam@/home/sam/code/ros/sam_nav/ira_navigation/teleop_ira_robot/launch$      sudo apt-get install libqt4-sql-psql
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
 requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
 distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
 or been moved out of Incoming.
 The following information may help to resolve the situation:
 
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libqt4-sql-psql : Depends: libqt4-sql (= 4:4.7.0-0ubuntu4) but      4:4.7.0-0ubuntu4.3 is to be installed
                    Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.7.0-0ubuntu4) but      4:4.7.0-0ubuntu4.3 is to be installed
 E: Broken packages
 
 sam@/home/sam/code/ros/sam_nav/ira_navigation/teleop_ira_robot/launch$
```

I run 'sudo dpkg -l | grep qt4':

```
 sam@/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch$      sudo dpkg -l | grep qt4

 ii  libqglviewer-qt4-2                             2.3.4-2                                                an OpenGL 3D viewer library based on Qt - runtime library
 ii  libqglviewer-qt4-dev                           2.3.4-2                                                an OpenGL 3D viewer library based on Qt4 - development files
 ii  libqt4-core                                    4:4.7.0-0ubuntu4.3                                     transitional package for Qt 4 core non-GUI runtime libraries
 ii  libqt4-dbus                                    4:4.7.0-0ubuntu4.3                                     Qt 4 D-Bus module
 ii  libqt4-declarative                             4:4.7.0-0ubuntu4.3                                     Qt 4 Declarative module
 ii  libqt4-designer                                4:4.7.0-0ubuntu4.3                                     Qt 4 designer module
 ii  libqt4-dev                                     4:4.7.0-0ubuntu4.3                                     Qt 4 development files
 ii  libqt4-help                                    4:4.7.0-0ubuntu4.3                                     Qt 4 help module
 ii  libqt4-network                                 4:4.7.0-0ubuntu4.3                                     Qt 4 network module
 ii  libqt4-opengl                                  4:4.7.0-0ubuntu4.3                                     Qt 4 OpenGL module
 ii  libqt4-opengl-dev                              4:4.7.0-0ubuntu4.3                                     Qt 4 OpenGL library development files
 ii  libqt4-qt3support                              4:4.7.0-0ubuntu4.3                                     Qt 3 compatibility library for Qt 4
 ii  libqt4-script                                  4:4.7.0-0ubuntu4.3                                     Qt 4 script module
 ii  libqt4-scripttools                             4:4.7.0-0ubuntu4.3                                     Qt 4 script tools module
 ii  libqt4-sql                                     4:4.7.0-0ubuntu4.3                                     Qt 4 SQL module
 ii  libqt4-sql-mysql                               4:4.7.0-0ubuntu4.3                                     Qt 4 MySQL database driver
 ii  libqt4-sql-sqlite                              4:4.7.0-0ubuntu4.3                                     Qt 4 SQLite 3 database driver
 ii  libqt4-svg                                     4:4.7.0-0ubuntu4.3                                     Qt 4 SVG module
 ii  libqt4-test                                    4:4.7.0-0ubuntu4.3                                     Qt 4 test module
 ii  libqt4-xml                                     4:4.7.0-0ubuntu4.3                                     Qt 4 XML module
 ii  libqt4-xmlpatterns                             4:4.7.0-0ubuntu4.3                                     Qt 4 XML patterns module
 ii  libqwt5-qt4                                    5.2.0-1build1                                          Qt4 widgets library for technical applications (runtime)
 ii  libqwt5-qt4-dev                                5.2.0-1build1                                          Qt4 widgets library for technical applications (development)
 ii  python-qt4                                     4.7.4-0ubuntu1                                         Python bindings for Qt4
 ii  qt4-designer                                   4:4.7.0-0ubuntu4.3                                     graphical designer for Qt 4 applications
 ii  qt4-dev-tools                                  4:4.7.0-0ubuntu4.3                                     Qt 4 development tools
 ii  qt4-doc                                        4:4.7.0-0ubuntu4.3                                     Qt 4 API documentation
 ii  qt4-qmake                                           4:4.7.0-0ubuntu4.3                                Qt 4 qmake Makefile      generator tool
 
 sam@/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch$
```

How to solve it?
Thank you~

---

Original version of full output message:

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/a52a1ee9601ccd8a8323495a044e7902

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10865/failed-dependencies-when-install-diamondback/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2246 on 2011-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

he sam

when you run the command

> sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-*

you try to install every single package/stack available this way. this is way more than just normal diamondback.
install instructions for diamondback can be found here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Installation

about those dependencies, have you tried installing the dependencies with apt-get install, when i check it shows them as available (you might have to do an apt-get update)

---

Originally posted by [Bram van de Klundert](https://answers.ros.org/users/392/bram-van-de-klundert/) with karma: 241 on 2011-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-08-21**:
Thank you~The message is changed to english version successfully. I have updated the original post to english version of output messages.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-08-13**:
For me LC_MESSAGE=en_US.UTF8 works. But this only gives english messages, which would be easier than translating. To solve the actual problem try the suggestion by Bram an post errors from that in english.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-08-13**:
I can run export LANG=en_US , but when I run export LC_MESSAGES=en_US, it shows that bash: warning: setlocale: LC_MESSAGES: cannot change locale (en_US): No such file or directory. What can I do next? Thank you~

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-08-12**:
In that case a translation is probably better ;) You can try export LANG=en_US and export LC_MESSAGES=en_US in the console you run the install from. In any way, can you give the information requested by tfoote and try the suggestion by Bram.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-08-12**:
I know typing is not the best way,but my output is chinese,I have tried to change it to english version,but not works. So I try to translate the original message to english version. I have successfully installed ROS by that command before,but now it would not work. I don't know why.Thank you~

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-08-10**:
I guess, the manual installation should lead to another error. When that happens, update the original post with those erros and the commands issued and always copy&paste the exact error messages instead of typing.